# How to create an array variable used as script argument in Gitlab CI yaml file?

Tags: shell, gitlab-ci

I'm trying to figure out how to declare a variable that is an array and use it as arguments passed to a shell script. Or find out how to be a bit more DRY by learning how to

Here's what I have tried that causes `/bin/sh: eval: line X: syntax error: bad substitution`:

```
variables:
  EXTRA_ARGS: (. "${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA} pipeline-${CI_PIPELINE_ID} latest" "pipeline-${CI_PIPELINE_ID}" $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG)

build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - path/to/script.sh uniqueParam1 uniqueParam2 ${EXTRA_ARGS[@]}
    - path/to/script.sh uniqueParam3 uniqueParam4 ${EXTRA_ARGS[@]}
    - path/to/script.sh uniqueParam5 uniqueParam6 ${EXTRA_ARGS[@]}
```

And the follow runs fine, but as you can tell, I'm repeating the extra arguments:

```
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - path/to/script.sh uniqueParam1 uniqueParam2 . "${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA} pipeline-${CI_PIPELINE_ID} latest" "pipeline-${CI_PIPELINE_ID}" $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    - path/to/script.sh uniqueParam3 uniqueParam4 . "${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA} pipeline-${CI_PIPELINE_ID} latest" "pipeline-${CI_PIPELINE_ID}" $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
    - path/to/script.sh uniqueParam5 uniqueParam6 . "${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA} pipeline-${CI_PIPELINE_ID} latest" "pipeline-${CI_PIPELINE_ID}" $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG
```

I've also tried to remove the `.` dot, as an argument, but the error persists.

For my sake of mind I tried to run the concept in bash, and ran with success as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

TEST1="Hello"
TEST2="human!"

ARGS=(. $TEST1 $TEST2 "${TEST2} ${TEST1}" "param1" "param2")

echo "${ARGS[*]}"
```

Outputs:

```
. Hello human! human! Hello param1 param2
```

Also tried to put it in the scripts as:

```
script:
  - EXTRA_ARGS=(. "${CI_COMMIT_SHORT_SHA} pipeline-${CI_PIPELINE_ID} latest" "pipeline-${CI_PIPELINE_ID}" $CI_COMMIT_REF_NAME $CI_COMMIT_REF_SLUG)
```

And also doesn't work:

```
/bin/sh: eval: line 92: syntax error: unexpected "("
```

Also tried to escape `\(` but did not work.

Comment: `/bin/sh` (most probably) is not bash. Your docker inside gitlab is not running bash.

Comment: You're absolutely right @KamilCuk I'll see if I can change the runner to bash as unix shell does not support array I think

Comment: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/1758

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by the first comment, the issue is related to the Docker image that is based in Alpine that has bourne shell and not bash by default.

https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/issues/1758

Answer (score 1):

The following works with me for the same case, with a minor difference that *I  define the array as a variable instead of sending it as an argument*.

In `.getlab-ci.yml`, I export a "string" variable that has the elements concatenated and delimited by `';'` (with single quotes, escaping `;`):

```
build:
  stage: build 
  variables:
    ELMNT1: Value Has Spaces
    ELMNT2: Another Value Has Spaces
  script: 
    - export MY_ARR_STR=${ELMNT1}';'${ELMNT2}
    - shell my_script.sh
```

In the script, I convert the string to an array:

`my_script.sh`

```
ORIG_IFS="$IFS"
IFS=";" read -a MY_ARR <<< $MY_ARR_STR
IFS="$ORIG_IFS"
for index in "${!MY_ARR[@]}";
do
    echo "Array Element at index '$index' is '${MY_ARR[$index]}'"
done
```

With output as

```
Array Element at index '0' is 'Value Has Spaces'
Array Element at index '1' is 'Another Value Has Spaces'
```

Answer (score 0):

In `sh`, you can also create an array variable from a string, as shown in  https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/569471/shell-convert-string-to-array

Here is how I use it in Gitlab CI to build Docker images from the kaniko container that has `sh` shell:

```yaml
.build-kaniko:
  image:
    name: gcr.io/kaniko-project/executor:debug
    entrypoint: ['']
  variables:
    CONTEXT_DIR: ''
    IMAGE_DESTINATION_URI: ''
    KANIKO_EXTRA_ARGS: '--target prod --build-arg foo=bar'
  script:
    # Convert KANIKO_EXTRA_ARGS to shell array variable
    # https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/569471/shell-convert-string-to-array
    - set -o noglob
    - IFS=' '
    - 'set -- "$KANIKO_EXTRA_ARGS"'
    - 'echo "KANIKO_EXTRA_ARGS: " "$@"'

    # Run kaniko command
    - /kaniko/executor
      --context "$CONTEXT_DIR"
      --destination "$IMAGE_DESTINATION_URI"
      --skip-unused-stages=true
      $@
```